# The bing map control for wp7 has two properties called Pitch and Heading, but setting those two properties does not seem to work

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, bing, pitch, heading

The bing map control for wp7 has two properties called Pitch and Heading, but setting those two properties does not seem to work. 
I expect them to rotate the map.

Am I missing anything? 
Is there anything specific that needs to be done to make those two properties work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That properties aren't avilable now on WP7. This is propertis for 3D Bing Map Control (rather desktop), not supported by WP7 yet.

Better use transform on container with map (i.e. Canvas, but I can't check now...)