# Setting Heading for Silverlight Bing Maps Control in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589031%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) from Microsoft's documentation, it's possible to set the heading of a Bing map as well as the coordinate around which it's centered and a zoom level using the method call `setView(GeoCoordinate, double, double)` but in practice, only the first two parameters are paid attention to and when I check the value of `myMap.Heading` it's still 0. I've also tried directly changing the heading (`myMap.Heading=270;`) and the same thing happens. Can anyone offer some assistance?

Note: Heading is supposed to be in degrees starting at 0 for north and increasing clockwise. ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681898.aspx))

I found an [old topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268312/the-bing-map-control-for-wp7-has-two-properties-called-pitch-and-heading-but-se) about this, but it was posted in 2011, apparently before this was implemented in WP (unless it still isn't but the documentation would suggest otherwise).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Heading property is only functional in Birdseye (i.e. oblique) view, in order to specify whether you want a North, East, South, or West aspect.

You might find this post helpful: http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/rotating-bing-maps/